# Why doesn't the Spanish site have a "vote to close" option under the question like other sites?

Tags: soporte, votos-de-cierre, privilegios

Other sites have an option to close questions. Why doesn't the Spanish one have this? This Meta has it, but the main site does not.

Comment: You have tens of thousands of reputations on some other sites and still don't know how reputations work? Each user should go to the site tour from the beginning. If not, there's still meta-questions that ask about reputations and their usage.

Answer (score 7):

It has it, only that you don't have enough reputation to see it:

> Help Center > Privileges > [Cast close and reopen votes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)
>
> Awarded at: 500 reputation

Once you reach the 500 points you will be able to see the `close` option below every question. In the meanwhile, you can do it through another privilege you already have:

> Help Center > Privileges > [Flag posts](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
>
> Awarded at: 15 reputation
>
> Flagging is a way of bringing inappropriate content to the attention of the community. The currently implemented flag types are the following:
>
> ...
>
> 4. Flag to close (questions only)

---

Regarding you having this privilege in Meta but not on the main site: it does not have to do with being in Meta or main, since privileges are the same in both. It has to do with you being the owner of the question. From [What is a “closed”, “on hold”, or “duplicate” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/209901):

> **Who can close a question?**
>
> - Users with at least 250 rep may vote to close their own questions
> - ...

Since you have 445 points now, you are exactly in the position of being able to close your own posts but not others'. I cross checked with some accounts I have in other sites and it is the case.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99692/discussion-on-answer-by-fedorqui-why-doesnt-the-spanish-site-have-a-vote-to-cl).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on this, but I think this is what's going on: when a user account hasn't yet reached the threshold for being able to vote to close a question (500 pts), the word "close" won't be visible.  EXCEPTION: apparently the threshold for seeing the "close" button on one's OWN question is lower (250 pts).

---

I took a look at a site where I have between 250 and 500 points in reputation.  Here are screenshots:

- Someone else's question (note, no "close" link):

  [image: someone else's question]
- My own question (with "close" link):

  [image: my own question]

Comment: @Lambie: I can confirm these findings in Spanish Language: my reputation is currently 340 and: in someone's question, I can't see the close link, but in my own questions I can see it (and even the number of closing votes it has), like in https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31478/qu%C3%A9-errores-contiene-o-ha-contenido-el-diccionario-de-la-lengua-de-la-rae